# How do i display a Angular component inside another Angular component

Tags: angular, routes

Suppose i have two components, `Component1` and `Component2`. Out of which `Component2` takes some parameters to render.

Is it possible to display the contents of `Component2` inside `Component1` only. And trigger those parameters on mere click of buttons?

For example, 
Assume i have `GalleryComponent` and `ArtsComponent`.

```
  { path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent },
  { path: 'arts', 
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ArtsComponent, data :{ name:"all" } },
      { path: 'author/:id', component: ArtsComponent, data :{ name:"author" }},
      { path: 'form/:id', component: ArtsComponent, data :{ name:"form" } },
    ]
  }
```

Currently i am able to view both of these as following `URLS`,

```
localost:4200/gallery
localost:4200/arts
localost:4200/arts/author/1
localost:4200/art/form/1
```

And i am navigating via,

```
[routerLink]="['/arts/form', '1']"
```

And this will take me to new page, i.e. `localost:4200/art/form/1`, but i dont want that, i want to capture the content of this `URL` at my `GalleryComponent` only, something like,

```
//gallery.component.html
<a [routerLink]="['/arts/form', '1']">Form1</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/arts/form', '2']">Form1</a>

<app-arts></app-arts>
```

Comment: where are you using `router-outlet`?

Comment: `router-outlet` has already been delared in `app.component.html` as `<app-nav><router-outlet></router-outlet></app-nav>`, and my `nav` component contains a SideNav thus all my rendered pages are falling in `<ng-content>` of that sidebar. And both of my `Gallery` and `Arts` are being placed under `<ng-content>`

Comment: To the person abusing `close` vote: Please provide a reason along with your vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest pretty much any number of components one under another, as long as that component has a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` where it would output the content of the child routes. The same way `app.component` works. So all you need to do is put the `router-outlet` inside a `galery.component.html` and in the routes config you would put the `ArtsComponent` inside children array of `GaleryComponent`. and after that you would also adjust your routes for `ArtsComponent`

```
[
  { 
    path: 'gallery', 
    component: GalleryComponent, 
  }, 
  { 
    path: 'arts', 
    component: GalleryComponent, 
    children: [ 
        { path: '', component: ArtsComponent, data :{ name:"all" } }, 
        { path: 'author/:id', component: ArtsComponent, data :{ name:"author"}}, 
        { path: 'form/:id', component: ArtsComponent, data :{ name:"form" }}, 
    ]
  },
]
----------------------------------
//gallery.component.html

<a [routerLink]="['/gallery/form', '1']">Form1</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/gallery']">All</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/gallery/author','1']">Author</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: I understand, but in this scenario i will lose all my `/arts/*` routes as they will be replaced by `/gallery/*`.

Comment: do this: `[
{ path: 'gallery', 
    component: GalleryComponent,
  },
{ path: 'arts', 
    component: GalleryComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', component: ArtsComponent, data :{ name:"all" } },
        { path: 'author/:id', component: ArtsComponent, data :{ name:"author" }},
        { path: 'form/:id', component: ArtsComponent, data :{ name:"form" } },
    ]
  },`

Comment: This'll work, but when i need to use `/art` from another component it'll give me gallery component along with it!

Comment: @Mercurial you mean, you want to display the `ArtsComponent` as a standalone page in `/art` route?

Comment: Ok, Suppose `ARTS` page contains only two numbers `100, 200`. And whenever we call art with param it'll return the respective number, that's all to it. i.e. on-calling `/art/1` gives `100` and `/art/2` gives 200. Now i want to use this `ARTS` from any component i like, eg. If i want to place `/art/1`  value in `Component1` i want only values from `ARTS` and i want to call `/art/1` from `Component2` too and so on.

Comment: Another example, suppose i have a component `spinner` containg `10 spinners`, now i want to place a specific spinner in any component i want! by calling it by params, like `spinner/1` and `spinner/2` and so on.

Comment: @Mercurial Yeah, I know what you mean. So this is a bit more complicated then just routes, you would have to create a component that can be both, routed, or created dynamically, it is a bit more code than that, I would gladly show you how to do it. But I think it is a bit outside of the scope of this question :D

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you need to add another `<router-outlet>` to your `gallery.component.html` and then add the art **routes** as children of the gallery component in your `module`

Comment: I was just suggesting @Nerijus that this will make me lose all my `/arts/*` routes as they will be replaced by `/gallery/*`. It's practically like creating new child routes and deleting previous ones.

Comment: Think of it as this, you don't have a route for your SideNav because it is not the "route" itself it's just "wrapping around" the real route, therefore (if I understood correctly) if you do what you want, your gallery component shouldn't have a route for itself, because it's wrapping arts, and you are going to change the content in that section, so you can replace your ```gallery``` route with ```arts``` route and keep them

Comment: I understand the `wrapping around` you are taking abour, but no, my gallery is dynamic and filling via API, this `arts` route is to only make it better by providing dynamic content there itself! Read comments here for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58413418/2207792

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
export class Component1 {


}
```

in the HTML plce your second component:

```
<app-component2></app-component2>
```

Comment: I did this and but as both of the components are registered in router, router will redirect to new clear page on new click!